# How to change post menu title names in Wordpress admin

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to change post menu title name (Tags) into (Keywords) and also want to change word tag/Tags with the word Keyword/Keywords in all places where Tag/Tags are used in WordPress admin panel.
Spouse:

```
Admin panel -> post -> tags
```

Here I want to change Tags heading into Keywords. and all the word like tag/tags in this page and all other pages want to change into Keyword/keywords.

Comment: It would probably be better to create a custom taxonomy called "keywords" that acts like tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the Wordpress code, in the wp-admin folder there's a file named menu-header.php which handles the creation of the menus.  Using the following function accesses the global variables defined in menu-header.php and modifies the label for 'Tags'.  Another file in the same directory is responsible for the Tags page, that's edit-tags.php.

You can place this within the functions.php file of your theme and it will change Post tags to Keywords

```
function change_post_menu_label() {
  global $menu;
  global $submenu;
  $submenu['edit.php'][16][0] = 'Keywords'; // Change name for tags
  echo '';
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'change_post_menu_label' );
```

Comment: this function only change the Post sub menu title. i also need to change tags page title (Tags) and on button (Add new tags) into add new keywrds